# Import textfile with weird column spacing

Tags: r, import

I am trying to import into a dataframe the four columns of a txt file from an internet url. The file has the following data structure:

```
20080713 20 28    999.99
20080723 17 50     -0.21
20080802 15 49     -0.21
20080812 13 47     -0.23
20080822 11 46     -0.27
20080901  9 44     -0.31
20080911  7 43     -0.38
```

In particular I am resorting to the `readr` package. Since I believe that the file is tab separated, i am using the `read_tsv` command.

```
read_tsv(data.txt)
```

However the results are not satisfactory as it only produces one meshed column, and it seems not detect any tab dividing columns there.

Even trying with a single space is not leading to a solution

```
read_delim(data.txt, delim = " ")
```

How should I approach the unknown spacing issue?

NB the original file is here:
https://ipad.fas.usda.gov/lakes/images/lake0534.TPJOJ.2.smooth.txt

Comment: Thanks, however 'data.table::fread()' works, while 'read_tsv' does not split the columns correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data in the textfile and you view the symbols in it, you can see that the separator between the columns are a space / multiple spaces.

If you want to use readr, you need to use the option to read in the data based on spaces. This is simply `read_table`:

```
lakes <- read_table("lake0534.TPJOJ.2.smooth.txt", skip = 12, col_names = FALSE)
head(lakes)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
        X1    X2    X3    X4
     <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
1 20080723    17    50 -0.21
2 20080802    15    49 -0.21
3 20080812    13    47 -0.23
4 20080822    11    46 -0.27
5 20080901     9    44 -0.31
6 20080911     7    43 -0.38
```

Just using base R's `read.table`:

```
lakes <- read.table("lake0534.TPJOJ.2.smooth.txt", skip = 12, header = FALSE)
head(lakes)
        V1 V2 V3    V4
1 20080723 17 50 -0.21
2 20080802 15 49 -0.21
3 20080812 13 47 -0.23
4 20080822 11 46 -0.27
5 20080901  9 44 -0.31
6 20080911  7 43 -0.38
```